# How to set a type object as initial value of React using Typescript and useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I just started learning build React apps with Typescript and I'm really stuck at this point.

I set a `type` to be the model of a state, but I'm getting this error:

[image]

This is what I'm doing:

```
type TAssetsOverview = {
    totalAssets: number,
    assetsInOperation: number,
    assetsInAlert: number,
    assetsInDowntime: number
}

const AssetsOverview: React.FC = () => {
    const [overview, setOverview] = React.useState<TAssetsOverview>({})
    return (
        <div>
            <AssetsList assets={assets} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default AssetsOverview
```

What I want to do is to set `overview` as an object based on `type TAssetsOverview`.

I tried to set the values within the object, like this:

```
const [overview, setOverview] = React.useState<TAssetsOverview>({
        totalAssets, 
        assetsInOperation, 
        assetsInAlert, 
        assetsInDowntime
    })
```

But I get this error:

[image]

If I remove `type TAssetsOverview` and just set `useState<{}>({})` it works fine, but I guess that's not how it should be done.

From where I see it looks exactly like all the tutorials and articles I read, but since I'm a newbie I can't see what is missing here.

How should I set this?

Comment: Did you try making the default value _actually correspond to the type_? Alternatively, if you don't have a sensible default, initialise it as undefined.

Comment: Are your fields optional, because your objects are of different structure : `{}` is not a valid value right

Comment: @jonrsharpe what you mean? like setting the properties within the object? I did, but I get that the values are not difeined in the scope.

Comment: So give a [mre] of that, what you currently have doesn't work for exactly the reason the message gives - that's not a valid overview value. It's unclear why you thought it _would_ be.

Comment: OK, so in the new version where did you think those values were coming from? That's not even a typescript problem, just basic JS - and again the error message has told you _exactly what it is_.

Comment: And what exactly didn't you understand from reading it? Did you research the message? Did you look up what shorthand properties are? Where did you think those values _were_ coming from? Realistically if you don't know basic JS then piling TS and React on top of it is going to be a struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a default value which must corresponds to `TAssetsOverview`:

In your case as the variables are numbers you can set it default to `0` if that helps your cause.

```
type TAssetsOverview = {
    totalAssets: number,
    assetsInOperation: number,
    assetsInAlert: number,
    assetsInDowntime: number
}

const AssetsOverview: React.FC = () => {
    const [overview, setOverview] = React.useState<TAssetsOverview>({
    totalAssets: 0,
    assetsInOperation: 0,
    assetsInAlert: 0,
    assetsInDowntime: 0
})
    return (
        <div>
            <AssetsList assets={assets} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default AssetsOverview
```

Comment: It works, thank you. SHould I always initialize the values like this?

Comment: Yes, also i've edited the answer please have a look. :)

Comment: @Berg_Durden if this answers your question, please mark it as your answer.

Comment: I'll do that. But I have to wait some minutes.

Comment: @Berg_Durden Ok no problem, until then you can see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html to get better understanding of typescript.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the types of `{}` and `TAssetsOverview` are not the same.

In `TAssetsOverview`, all attributes are required (to create an object of that type, all attributes have to be present) and in `{}`, you are not passing any of the attributes.

You do not have to pass any argument to `useState` and you can initialize the state as `undefined`:

```
const [overview, setOverview] = React.useState<TAssetsOverview>();
```

However, if you want to initialize the state with `{}`, probably your type definition is wrong and all the attributes in `TAssetsOverview` are optional (notice the `?`):

```
type TAssetsOverview = {
    totalAssets?: number,
    assetsInOperation?: number,
    assetsInAlert?: number,
    assetsInDowntime?: number
}

...

const [overview, setOverview] = React.useState<TAssetsOverview>({});
```

Comment: _probably your type definition is wrong and all the attributes in TAssetsOverview are optional_
You mean to say?:
probably your type definition is wrong, all the attributes in TAssetsOverview **have to be** optional